# Getting attributes from Event Listener target using the NameNodeMap

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image gallery that in wrapped in a div. Rather than assign `onclick` events to a finite list of images I assign the `onclick` to the wrapper div. Image information is provided by an ajax call and I loop through the response data creating HTML which I inject into the wrapper DIV. Now each image contains attributes that I use to pass to a light box/modal window later. Everything was fine but with adding more attributes to each image I have noticed the attributes are ordered differently when inspecting the images using IE or Firefox developer tools. The order is preserved in Chrome and older versions of IE an attribute of `complete="complete"` is created. This of course breaks my JavaScript code.

Thus I can no longer reply on the positioning due to the parser of the browser. I output my HTML as so:

```
<img src="abcSmall.jpg" alt="Some Flowers" data-username="Mr Sausage" data-bigPhotoUrl="abcBig.jpg" data-UserId="31333205" photoUploadDate="25/05/2014">
```

but in Firefox and IE this is coming out as

```
<img data-bigPhotoUrl="abcBig.jpg" data-username="Mr Sausage" alt="Some Flowers" data-UserId="31333205" photoUploadDate="25/05/2014" src="abcSmall.jpg">
```

So my means of getting the attribute values below is now useless in IE and Firefox

```
if(event.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {

      // this is src - event.target.attributes[0].value
      // this is alt - event.target.attributes[1].value
      // this is username - event.target.attributes[2].value
      // this is bigPhotoUrl - event.target.attributes[3].value
      // this is userId - event.target.attributes[4].value
      // this is photoUploadDate - event.target.attributes[5].value 

      // now i create HTML Nodes and Elements to pass as contents of a modal window using the items above

    }
```

so I have to now loop through the `NamedNodeMap` of `event.target.attributes` however I am unsure what is the best way to create a variable that has the name of the html attribute and takes the value of the property. To be honest I can't determine if the `NamedNodeMap` is an array or an object? Has anyone any advice on looping through the `NamedNodeMap` of `event.target.attributes` and creating JS variables or is there a better way for me to get these from the Javascript code, using `event.target["data-username"]` seems to return a `'undefined'`

If I have worded this really badly please say so and I shall revise this question.

Comment: I have just came across this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap

Comment: and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
    var attrs = {};
    $.map([].map.call(event.target.attributes, function(_attr) {
      return [_attr.name, _attr.value]
    }), function(v) {
      var value = ["src", "alt", "username"
                   ,"bigPhotoUrl", "userId"
                   , "photoUploadDate"]
      , name = $.grep(value, function(val, idx) {
          return val.toLowerCase() === v[0].replace(/data-/, "")
        })[0];
      return attrs[name] = v[1]
    });
    // `attrs` : object having `key` : `attributes.name` ,
    // `value` : `attributes.value`
    // console.log(attrs)
  };
});
```

```js
$("#wrapper").on("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
    var attrs = {};
    $.map([].map.call(event.target.attributes, function(_attr) {
      return [_attr.name, _attr.value]
    }), function(v, k) {
      var value = ["src", "alt", "username"
                   ,"bigPhotoUrl", "userId"
                   , "photoUploadDate"],
        name = $.grep(value, function(val, idx) {
          return val.toLowerCase() === v[0].replace(/data-/, "")
        })[0];
      return attrs[name] = v[1]
    });
    $("pre").append("<br />" + JSON.stringify(attrs, null, 4))
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click image
<br />
<div id="wrapper" title="click">
  <img data-bigPhotoUrl="abcBig.jpg" data-username="Mr Sausage" alt="Some Flowers" data-UserId="31333205" photoUploadDate="25/05/2014" src="abcSmall.jpg" />
</div>
<pre></pre>
```